# Django multi level querying

Tags: python, django

I am using my custom created User model and I have two basic models:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

class Topic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
```

Is there any way (without an external package like [Django-mptt](https://github.com/brosner/django-mptt/)) to query Topics which belong to a particular Subject and were created by a particular User? I mean when a user logs in, I want to make a list like that:

**Edited: here's the list that I want to make:**

Hello user. Thank you for logging in.

Your items:

- Subject 1

  - Topic 1
  - Topic 2
- Subject 2

  - Topic 1

etc.

I am not sure how to do that. It might be easy but I am just a beginner.

**Edit: the answer was a simple nested for loop, I am sorry for any confusion created.**

Comment: This isn't quite clear. You say you want to query a particular subject, but your example shows you displaying all subjects for the user's topics. What exactly do you want to query?

Comment: I am sorry, I have been coding for the whole day. I indeed want to query Topics, that are belong to particular Subject that were created by particular User: User > Subject > Topics - I want to make an object tree like in my posted question.

Comment: By saying 'particular subject and User', I assume you know what subject and User is when you do the querying, right? Then I don't get why you think this is hard.

Comment: A user can create a Subject and then he can create a Topic under that particular subject. In my app dashboard want to make an object tree for User to see when has logged in: I want to list his Subjects and then each of his Topic under each of his Subjects. The question is confusing because I messed it up a little bit, sorry. Now I have edited it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Edit: The answer was a simple nested for loop, I have probably missed some nested name or something, sorry for confusing you guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is still confusing, because there is still no querying of topics or subjects going on. You are simply iterating through a user's topics, and for each topic you are iterating through the subjects.

```
<ul>
  {% for topic in user.topic_set.all %}
    <li>{{ topic.title }}
      <ul>
        {% for subject in topic.subject_set.all %}
          <li>{{ subject.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```